# splitting a cell starting from a specific word in excel

Tags: excel, split, cell

I have an excel file with a cell which includes a sentence. In this sentence there is a word and i want my cell to be splitted after this word.This word which makes the split should be automatically deleted if it works, if not it can stay.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Say the word is *qwerty*.  Before:

[image]

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim qwerty As String, r As Range
    Dim v As String

    qwerty = " qwerty "

    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, qwerty) > 0 Then
            r.Value = Split(v, qwerty)(0)
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Split(v, qwerty)(1)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

To achieve:

[image]

Comment: Love the sample data!

Comment: @Jeeped  My granddaughter helped with the data!

Comment: Do you think it is worth changing `v = r.Text` to `v = Replace(r.Text, qwerty, qwerty, , , vbTextCompare)` to remove case-sensitivity?

Comment: @Jeeped  If the actual data has *case* issues, your suggestion would be necessary.............of more concern is if the sentence begins or ends with *qwerty* and does not have the encapsulating blanks!............but this is enough to get the user started.

Comment: Strictly speaking (and the OP has not offered much more than this) but the only real requirement was that the string was to be **split** and if **qwerty** was the first or last then it wouldn't actually be *Split*; just truncated. I think you're safe.